# how to plot multiple 3D gaussian distributions with matplotlib in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

i've been trying to plot 4 separate gaussian distributions in one plot
so far i've got this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


mu = [[-1, -1], [-1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 1]]
sig = [[[0.02, 0], [0, 0.01]], [[0.1, 0], [0, 0.05]], [[0.03, 0], [0, 0.01]], [[0.02, 0], [0, 0.08]]]
x = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.01)
y = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.01)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X
pos[:, :, 1] = Y
gaussians_list = []
for i in range(len(mu)):
    gaussians_list.append(multivariate_normal(mu[i], sig[i]))

# Make a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(len(mu)):
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, gaussians_list[i].pdf(pos), cmap='viridis', linewidth=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
plt.show()
```

[image]

but it seems like the 3 first distributions are being covered by the last one at the points that it's zero.
i'm looking for a way to :
draw the parts where distributions are not equal to zero so they would not cover each other
although i'm aware that i could sum them up to generate one single distribution but i was wondering if there is a way to make the code above work

thank you in advance

Comment: The code isn't runnable and contains errors which are probably not the ones you want to inquire about here. But without being able to run the code it's hard to understand which exact problem you face.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for informing me I just edited the code

Comment: Now I understand the problem. You can in principle filter/mask the data that is below a certain threshold to only show the peaks. But I think as long as the distributions are distinct enough, just summing them up it the easiest solution. In general, consider that mplot3d is not a real 3D rendering engine, so very often it has no chance to know which part of an artist is to be shown in front of behind.